# attachment files shows blank

Tags: c#, .net, email-attachments

this is my code, i am trying to send text file as attachment without storing it onto the disk....................................

```
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            mailMsg.To.Add("receiver@email.com");
            mailMsg.Subject = "Application Exception";

            MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(MS);
            Writer.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "hello");
            Writer.Flush();
            Writer.Dispose();

            // Create attachment
            ContentType ct = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
            Attachment attach =new Attachment(MS, ct);
            attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Exception Log.txt";

            // Add the attachment
            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attach);

            // Send Mail via SmtpClient
            mailMsg.Body = "An Exception Has Occured In Your Application- \n";
            mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("sender@email.com");
            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@email.com", "password");
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've written in the MemoryStream, the position is at the end of the stream. Set it back to the beginning by adding:

```
MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

right after you've finished writing to the stream and flushing the writer. So (part of) your code would look like this:

```
...
MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(MS);
Writer.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "hello");
Writer.Flush();
MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
...
```

**EDIT:**
You should avoid calling `Dispose` on your writer, since it also closes the underlying stream.

Comment: do you mean before writer.flush(); ?  @rickvdbosch

Comment: No.it gives an error : Cannot access a closed Stream.

Comment: Ok.its works if i remove 2 lines
`Writer.Flush();
Writer.Dispose();`